# Running Slick2D results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I have tried to run a simple game using Java and keep getting an error when I try to run this application.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe ...

I think my problem is that my JDK (12.0.2) does not support these Slick2D as it is "OutDated". If downgrading my Java Version is a solution can someone please explain how I can find a version of Java that supports Slick2D?

I have already set up my libraries in my IDE and set my path. I tried to run the same application in the newest Intellij and eclipse environments. I currently have JDK 12.0.2 installed and a 2015 version of LWJGL plus Slick2D installed.

```
package classPackage;

import org.newdawn.slick.*;

public class Game extends BasicGame{


        public Game(String gamename) {
            super(gamename);
        }

        @Override
        public void init(GameContainer gc) throws SlickException {
        }

        @Override
        public void update(GameContainer gc, int i) throws SlickException {
        }

        @Override
        public void render(GameContainer gc, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
            g.drawString("Howdy!", 10, 10);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                AppGameContainer appgc;
                appgc = new AppGameContainer(new Game("Simple Slick Game"));
                appgc.setDisplayMode(640, 480, false);
                appgc.start();
            } catch (SlickException ex) {

            }

        }


}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/misc/Unsafe
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.getUnsafeInstance(MemoryUtilSun.java:74)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtilSun$AccessorUnsafe.<init>(MemoryUtilSun.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.ReflectAccess.newInstance(ReflectAccess.java:166)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.ReflectionFactory.newInstance(ReflectionFactory.java:404)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:590)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.loadAccessor(MemoryUtil.java:375)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:63)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.setTitle(WindowsDisplay.java:522)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.setTitle(Display.java:541)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:312)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at lwjgl/org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at slick/org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.tryCreateDisplay(AppGameContainer.java:302)
    at slick/org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.access$000(AppGameContainer.java:34)
    at slick/org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$2.run(AppGameContainer.java:353)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:310)
    at slick/org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:348)
    at slick/org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at testGame/classPackage.Game.main(Game.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.misc.Unsafe
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 23 more
```

Comment: I figured out my own question last night. Turns out that yes my JDK did not support the library. I downgraded my JDK to 8 and it now works no problems. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this issue resolved by downgrading my jdk to 8. Thank you all I hope this will help someone in the future.